# Eclipse EGit and GWT/GAE

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I have a central GIT repository, so that i can work on the project from different computers.
However when i pull the project on the other computer i get the error "Unbound classpath container: 'GWT SDK [missing]' in project 'Test Project'" (I also get a similar error for GAE).

So my question is: How do i setup my project so the same version of GAE/GWT is used on all computers.

I suspect the problem could be caused by the different versions of GAE and GWT on the machines. For example: GWT (1) is not the same version on the machines as it depends on when you updated GWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem too, and solved it by installing the GAE and GWT sdks under specific names, manually.  That is, instead of relying on eclipse's software update tools, I downloaded the specific SDK version I wanted from the googlecode sites, and then added them manually to eclipse.  This way their names include the numbers, and your git repository can store information about which versions it's using.

I *do* have to install the sdks manually on each developer machine, which is a drag.

To install an sdk manually:

1. Download it
2. Right-click on the sdk container in eclipse (in project explorer, it probably says GWT SDK [missing])
3. Choose properties
4. Click configure SDKs
5. follow the path to install a new sdk

You don't have to set the new sdk as default or anything - your project will pick it up immediately after you install it.

Note to any GPE developers: it'd be nice if the sdks were installed automatically with a version-specific name for the benefit of source control!

Comment: Excellent answer, completely solved the problem! I'm nitpicking here but you should add a "2. extract it" step to the install guide. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Change the project's SDK target.

In eclipse go to Marker [it is a tab next on the extreme left of the tabs including Console and Development] --> Left Click problem indication --> Click Quick fixes and choose the option which re-configures the project. This should fix the problem. Note that if your code uses features that changed between SDK versions you will have to make changes.

Combined with Rilev Lark's answer This is a chance to Update your projects or your environments whenever the problem occurs.